# change password with python-ldap

Tags: python, passwords, ldap, python-ldap

I want change password on ldap user. The script is:

```
def changePassword(url,binddn,pw, newpw):
l = ldap.initialize(url)
ldap.
try:
    l.protocol_version=ldap.VERSION3
    l.simple_bind_s(binddn,pw)
except:
    print "Error Bind in changePassword"
    sys.exit(0)

old = {'userPassword':pw}
new = {'userPassword':newpw}
ldif = modlist.modifyModlist(old,new)
try:
    l.modify_s(binddn,ldif)
    l.unbind_s()
except:
    print "error"
```

But when I call this function, I receive "error".
My LDAP has PPolicy for require current password when I change password.

How to change password whit this PPolicy??

Can anyone help me??

Thanks in advance
Dario

Comment: What if you remove the `try/except` - how does it fail? Thanks.

Comment: if remove `try/except` first and after `l.modify_s` I receive the error **ldap.UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM: {'info': 'The password policy requires that user password changes include the current password in the request', 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to perform'}**

Answer (score 1):

With an LDAPv3 server, you should generally never do a direct mod/replace on a user password, and instead use the LDAPv3 Password modify operation.  Using python-ldap, this is done with passwd/passwd_s.  For example:

```
import ldap
server = 'localhost'
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://%s' % server)
l.simple_bind_s("cn=Marice McCaugherty,ou=Product Testing,dc=example,dc=com", "ytrehguaCc")
l.passwd_s("cn=Marice McCaugherty,ou=Product Testing,dc=example,dc=com", "ytrehguaCc", "secret")
```

Would bind as the user DN listed, and change their password from "ytrehguaCc" to "secret".

Comment: You might want to add an example on how to do it. It would be helpful for people facing similar issues.

Comment: import ldap
client = ldap.initialize("ldap://test.com:389")
client.simple_bind_s("cn=nihao2,ou=test,dc=test,dc=com", 'nihao123!')
client.passwd_s('cn=nihao2,ou=test,dc=test,dc=com', 'nihao123!', 'hello456@')

then, I got a ERROR like this:
`PROTOCOL_ERROR                            Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 client.passwd_s(cn=nihao2,ou=test,dc=test,dc=com', 'nihao123!', 'hello456@')
...
PROTOCOL_ERROR: {'info': u'0000203D: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AA, comment: Unknown extended request OID, data 0, v3839', 'desc': u'Protocol error'}`

Comment: What LDAP server are you using?

Comment: I used windows AD, when I change my the protocol with SSL, it become OK, just because I use it without SSL certs.When I used AD with SSL, used the attribution `unicodePwd` to set and change the password is OK.

Comment: AD is not LDAP, it is LDAP like.  It has various behaviors that violate the protocol.

Comment: the given example helped me too, though I would add `l.unbind_s()` to the example to disconnect and free up ldap-server ressources after binding.

Comment: I left off the unbind in case there were further actions one may want to take. A well written LDAP server will simply close the connection if an unbind wasn't issued, although it is definitely nicer to do an unbind if your work on the connection is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use following modlist [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'userPassword', [newpasswd] )] directly in modify_s